# AttributeError: 'Concatenate' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, keras, concatenation

```
model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1),activation='relu',input_shape=(48,48,3),padding='same'))
model_1.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(7,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_1.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(1,7), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_1.add(BatchNormalization())
model_1.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2)))
model_1.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))

model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_2.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(1,3), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_2.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(1,7), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_2.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(7,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())

model_3 = Sequential()
model_3.add(BatchNormalization())
model_3.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2)))
model_3.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model_3.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1), activation='relu'))
model_3.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1), activation='relu'))
model_3.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2)))
model_3.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))
model_3.add(Dense(NUM_CLASS))
model_3.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))
model_3.add(Dense(NUM_CLASS, activation='softmax'))

#Concatenate
merged = Concatenate([model_1,model_2])
result =  Concatenate([merged,model_3])

result.compile(optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
result.summary()
```

I am trying to concatenate the feature maps outputted by the inception module.

[image]

It shows this error message.

```
AttributeError: 'Concatenate' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Paper from [IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8392744)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Do note that this is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related problems. Thus, in the future make sure to [edit] your questions to include the tag of the language you are programming in. That way, other users of that language can find your question much easier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, you **can't** concatenate `tf.keras.models.Model` objects together. It's not something defined for models, but only for `tf.keras.layers.Layer` objects.

When such operations are involved in a model (e.g. concatenation of outputs), it's best to use the `Functional` API. For example, your code can be rewritten the following way using the `Funcational` API.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPool2D, Dropout, Dense, Input, Concatenate

input_img = Input(shape=(48,48,3))

out_1_1 = Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1),activation='relu',input_shape=(48,48,3),padding='same')(input_img)
out_1_2 = Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(7,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_1_1)
out_1_3 = Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(1,7), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_1_2)
out_1_4 = BatchNormalization()(out_1_3)
out_1_5 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2))(out_1_4)
out_1_6 = Dropout(rate=0.2)(out_1_5)

out_2_1 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_1_6)
out_2_2 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(1,3), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_2_1)
out_2_3 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(1,7), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_2_2)
out_2_4 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(7,1), strides=(1), activation='relu',padding='same')(out_2_3)
out_2_5 = BatchNormalization()(out_2_4)

merged = Concatenate()([out_1_6,out_2_5])
```

Then you define your `model_3` outputs similarly and you can get your final output from `model_3`. Assume the output of `model_3` is `out_3_x`. Then you define your final model as.

```
result =  Concatenate()([merged,out_3_x])

full_model = tf.keras.layers.Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=result)

full_model.compile(optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
full_model.summary()
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you can describe difference between `Functional API` and `Sequential` approach please

Comment: Function API works as I've shown. You define layers first and then you create a Model. Whereas in Sequential API You define your model first and then keep adding layers sequentially. You can read more at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional